# What is a proper way to handle a "sequence number" like field?

Tags: ms-access

The fields of a trimmed-down version of a database I'm working with looks like this:

Model Number, Model Name, Customer, Date, SeqNum

The customer can purchase the exact same item on the same date so we're going to use a sequence number to distinguish the rows. So entries might look like:

```
AS-23423, Box, John Doe, 01/22/2013, 00
AS-23423, Box, John Doe, 01/22/2013, 01
AS-23423, Box, John Doe, 01/22/2013, 02
AS-23445, Pen, John Doe, 01/22/2013, 00
AS-23454, Case, John Doe, 01/22/2013, 00
AS-23423, Box, Mary Lyn, 01/22/2013, 00
AS-23423, Box, Mary Lyn, 01/22/2013, 01
```

How should you handle the sequence number if an application has to be CRUD compliant? I've considered doing MAX(SeqNum) + 1 upon inserting but this seems off especially when handling update and delete, so I figured there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access, this is more about code than design, unless you decide instead on an autonumber, which provides the required unique field and is much easier and safer. Otherwise, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949603/access-vba-find-max-number-in-column-and-add-1/11950647#11950647, you will find the following notes:

This requires a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library

Sequential Numbers

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim lngResult As Long
Dim strCon As String

    lngResult = 0  'assume fail

    strCon = "Provider=" ''Connection to back-end
    cn.Open strCon

    rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    rs.LockType = adLockPessimistic
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer

    ''Where BEInfo is a single line table
    strSQL = "SELECT ASeqNumber FROM BEInfo"

    rs.Open strSQL, cn, , , adCmdText

    'Note this is ADO, so no rs.Edit
    rs!ASeqNumber = rs!ASeqNumber + 1
    rs.Update

    lngResult = rs!ASeqNumber

    ''This should not happen, but just to be sure
    If DCount("ASeqNumber", "Table", "ASeqNumber=" & lngResult) > 0 Then
        lngResult = 0
    End If
```